# How to copy data from qa env yo dev env in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I deleted some csv files from Dev environment so i want to copy those files from qa env to dev environment. I am using Azure databricks, azure DevOps.

Any suggestions? How can i copy data

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share the blockers/errors that occurred during the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is download the file from QA environment and upload that file through storage explorer into Development environment